# Wordpress Category Loop Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error

So I have a category page setup on my word press page. But the loop is written with a `previous_post()` php function and I can't figure out how to remove it without cause a fatal php code error. A push of the code is below.

```
    <?php
/**
* The template for displaying Category pages
 *
*/
 ?>
 <?php get_header(); ?>


    <div id="archive_content">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php
                // Start the Loop.
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); {

                /*
                 * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
                 * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
                 * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'content', 'exchange-category' ); }

                endwhile;
                // Previous/next page navigation.
                 previous_post();

            else :
                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

            endif;
        ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</section><!-- #primary -->

 <?php
     get_footer(); ?>
```

So for example if you go to: http://www.bluestarnj.com/?it_exchange_category=d-bc it shows the previous post(product) I looked at. I can't figure out how to setup the loop properly so that all it does is call my content-exchange-category.php page and the wordpress codex is extremely confusing on this manner.

Thanks
Baroti

Comment: Remove the picture, edit the question and add the relevant code.

Comment: Sorry just figured a push out of jedit would be easier to read, but there I just set it to code format, I hope that helps.

Comment: Does the fatal error occur when you comment out the `previous_post();` line?